# representation of extraspecial group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H=\langle x,y\rangle$ be a non abelian group of order $p^3$ which has exponent equal to $p$. Also let $G$ be an extraspecial group of order $p^{2r+1}$ exponent $p$. We know that $G$ is isomorphic with central product of $r$ copy of $H$. I want to know if we can say any thing more about presentation of $G$? for example if $r=2$, then how we can say about representation of $G$? is it generated by its elements? and what we know about the commutator of its generated elements?

Comment: "I want to know if we can say any thing more about presentation of $G$", or "...about the *representation* of $G$"?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it generated by its elements"? Any group will be generated by its elements.

Comment: I am sorry, representation is better

Comment: not by all elements. for example in case of $p^5$, is it generated just by 5  its elements

Comment: It is also generated by all its elements.

Comment: yes it is clear that every groups is generated  by all its elements. But I mean that I want to know if this group is generated by just 5 elements? Also I want to know about the commutator of its generated elements.

Comment: Then please try to be more precise. You seem to be switching between representation and presentation at various places (these are not the same thing), and how could anyone guess that "its elements" was to mean "5 of its elements"?

Comment: An extraspecial group of order $p^{2k+1}$ cane be generated by $2k$ elements, and no fewer, because $G/Z(G)$ is elementary abelian.